# Usuário tentando retaliar com votos negativos (Suspeita)

Tags: debate, suporte, votos, voto-contra

Eu sei que não tem como saber quem votou negativo e apenas uma situação aonde há uma sequencias de votos negativos é que poderá ser possível reverter, sinceramente o votos não me fazem muita diferença neste momento, o meu problema é que as respostas e perguntas que recebi o voto negativo parecem ruins por tal motivo e ao meu ver são respostas/perguntas boas

Tudo começou ontem quando votei negativo nesta pergunta:

- [Como resolver vários erros deste código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75952/3635)

Então tive a **infeliz** ideia de [comentar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75952/como-resolver-v%C3%A1rios-erros-deste-c%C3%B3digo#comment155169_75952) o motivo do meu voto negativo, para tentar ser legal e ajudá-lo:

> -1 pelo mal título e por usar uma "foto" pra apresentar o problema, quando (o que dificulta pessoas com mesmo problema encontrarem está pergunta)

Eu iria retirar o voto negativo assim que ele editasse para a pergunta ser algo proveitoso, no entanto em menos de um (1) minuto recebi um voto negativo, então pensei "só pode ser o usuário da postagem que acabei de negativar".

Admito que fiz errado e não tinha certeza, mas comentei isto pro usuário:

> E é isso o que eu ganho por fazer o favor de justificar um voto negativo >:( - Todo mundo fala justifique o voto, mas você justifica e as pessoas começam a levar pro lado mau... Ao invés de fazer isto, edite o título da sua pergunta e troque as imagens por texto e eu retiro o -1... não precisa retaliar.

Mas fiquei muito aborrecido, no entanto hoje resolvi ficar quieto, porém a alguns minutos ganhei `-1` nesta postagem:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69766/3635

A resposta responde claramente ao problema e só não é melhor que a outra pois não apresenta uma solução "alternativa".

Eu sei que é errado acusar, mas o tal usuário já teve algumas atitudes inapropriadas com a comunidade, que não vêm ao caso.

Eu realmente **NUNCA** mais vou justificar voto negativo algum e se possível irei evitar de dar votos negativos.

Eu poderia retaliar de volta, mas prefiro debater o assunto e dar a oportunidade do usuário se defender.

Gostaria de saber o porquê da atitude e o que fazer com este tipo de situação.

Comment: -1 "Então tive a infeliz ideia de comentar o motivo do meu voto negativo, para tentar ser legal e ajuda-lo"

Comment: Pelo que vi no seu histórico, você "só" levou dois negativos nos últimos dias, isso ainda não é o suficiente para reverter caso suas suspeitas sejam certas.

Comment: O usuário em questão não votou hoje e ele foi visto pela última vez no site há 18h, então não pode ser ele que deu o voto negativo de hoje... PS: moderadores não têm o poder de ver quem votou em qual publicação, estou usando métodos tradicionais de investigação para averiguar o caso :)

Comment: @Gabe tem mais "retalhar" no texto para editar...

Comment: @JorgeB. Então edite ;p

Comment: @Math não pedi pra reverter :) é outra coisa o que eu quero dizer, visando que é um usuário que já teve más "atitudes" aqui.

Comment: @Math eu achei que fosse ele não com a mesma conta, mas sim pelo motivo anterior que ele ocasionou algum tipo de problema (múltiplas contas e manipulação de votos se eu não me engano)

Comment: @JorgeB. Já viu o motivo que eu participo do portuguese.SE :) -- cometo gafes de escrita direto kk- perdoe-me

Comment: Acho que de vez em quando é normal "perder a estribeira", ainda mais um power user como você. Mas sugiro tomar mais cuidado com acusações, isso é grave; guarde as para si enquanto não tiver certeza absoluta. Não vejo nada grave neste caso específico, em que a acusação é apenas de retirar um voto... mas, porém, contudo, entretanto, fica a dica. Você é um cara gente boa e que ajuda muito a comunidade, não vá se complicar por bobagem. Abraço.

Comment: @gustavox 3 até o momento. De ontem pra hoje.

Comment: 3 votos? Mas o  Gabe já disse que não foram do mesmo cara... Mas pô, não me leve a mal cara, vc sempre me ajuda, não estou aqui te criticando não, só dando um toque mesmo.

Comment: Eu não to te levando a mal rs, só disse que foram 3, e como eu disse pro gabe, o usuário já foi banido uma vez por manipulação de votos, ou seja ele tem mais de uma conta, não tem como determinar se foi ele ou não.

Comment: Ah tá, saquei, é que já passei por algo parecido uma vez, quando publiquei [um artigo](http://gustavoborceda.jusbrasil.com.br/artigos/112072225/a-nova-acao-revisional-do-fgts-para-recuperacao-das-perdas-e-alteracao-da-tr-como-indice-de-correcao-monetaria-1999-2013-parte-i) sobre a questão da correção monetária do FGTS, e pensei estar sendo "vítima de uma ataque de votos negativos em massa". No dia tive certeza de que estavam vindo de uma sala da CEF (rs)...

Comment: mas depois o pessoal do site explicou que (além de outras coisas) muitas vezes as pessoas pensavam que o lugar destinado ao voto era pra rolar a página pra baixo, e que isso estava gerando muitos votos negativos... o que quero dizer é que por mais que faça sentido, às vezes tem uma explicação mais simples...

Comment: @gustavox Kkkkk sério? Putz essa deveria ir pro blog do http://vidadesuporte.com.br :)

Comment: Retirei o -1 era só para você lembrar que deve continuar comentar quando dá -1 :)

Answer (score 20):

## Errado, errado, errado.

Já abriste uma sinalização para a moderação ver se é o caso?

Mesmo que tenha sido o AP a fazer isso, perdeste a razão toda ao acusá-lo sem provas. Primeiro deverias ter aberto uma sinalização expondo o teu problema para que a moderação pudesse verificar esse caso. Eles mesmos tomariam alguma medida caso fosse necessário.

A melhor resposta que podes dar a um utilizador que não respeita as pessoas é seres educado e reto com ele. Ainda a pouco um utilizador insultou-me, eu respondi-lhe com tanta calma e simpatia que ele acabou por editar o comentário ;)

> "Eu realmente NUNCA mais vou justificar voto negativo algum e se possível irei evitar de dar votos negativos."

Por causa do suposto mau comportamento de um utilizador vais fazer como ele e ser vingativo?

Continua a justificar os teus -1 quanto achares que deves justificar como nesse caso.

Comment: Ótima resposta, votarei em você para ser moderador no PL e nas próximas eleições do SOPT :)

Comment: @Math Numa resposta consegui dois votos para eleições? Categoria :P

Comment: Ok, votarei para moderador apenas do PL

Comment: @Math e com um comentário perdi um voto :(

Comment: Se fosse quase certeza, certeza, certeza, então eu sinalizaria, como não é caso de certeza, certeza, certeza, então preferi debater. Espero que entenda,entenda,entenda o que perguntei :p

Comment: Entendo que fui precipitado e realmente reconheço a situação e concordo com quase tudo dito por ti. A situação foi que é um usuário já com um certo histórico de problemas. Mas acho que "argumentar" realmente aqui não vai ter efeito positivo e nem vai ter retorno algum pra ninguém. Devido aos seus argumentos serem mais fortes que os meus irei deletar a pergunta a seguir. Compreendi a situação obrigado :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não apagues a pergunta. Serve pra futuros utilizadores que tenham a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Hoje fico feliz de ter seguido o teu conselho de não apagar a pergunta, hoje vi acontecer o mesmo que aconteceu comigo com um outro colega, a pergunta e respostas aqui parecem úteis pra estes tipo de situação :) - assim espero.!! Obrigado.

Comment: É mesmo isso amigo.

Answer (score 12):

De maneira alguma 2 votos negativos, dados em um intervalo de 20 horas, são base para reversão ou investigação. Mesmo que fossem dados pela mesma pessoa, o que não aconteceu.

Mesmo na hipótese de que ambos os votos fossem dados pelo Rodolfo - o que, repito, não é verdade - e que os votos fossem dados apenas em retaliação ao seu comentário, com essa frequência é mais provável que eles tivessem sido dados a posts dos quais ele *realmente* discorda. E isso é prerrogativa de todo usuário aqui.

O problema é o voto contra *em série*, dados em rápida sucessão ou não. Algo claramente feito com o objetivo de atingir o autor e não de qualificar os posts. Não foi o caso aqui. Você recebeu votos contras normais que são parte de estar no site há tanto tempo, e participar tanto.

Você está no site desde o começo, é bastante ativo na comunidade, tem excelentes posts e mostra um cuidado grande com a qualidade do que faz. Seu zelo com o site se reflete no seu status como um dos usuários de maior reputação e, concordando com o Jorge B., a maior parte dos seus atos tem como objetivo o bem estar da comunidade. Parar de fazer um deles por ter tido uma reação adversa não acrescenta nada.

Ao invés de focar nesse caso, tente se lembrar do quanto todos os seus comentários já ajudaram pessoas a melhorarem seus posts e conseguirem suas respostas. **Esse** é o seu impacto no site. Sofrer retaliação por fazer a coisa certa não apaga todo o bom impacto que você já teve até hoje, e vai ter ainda mais se continuar fazendo a coisa certa.

Comment: +2 pelo último paragrafo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se tiver dando +2 vou investigar seu sockpuppet :D

Comment: Quero que tanto você quanto o @JorgeB. entendam que a situação é devido o usuário já ter um "histórico de problemas" anterior. Independente disto, o argumento de ambos realmente é mais forte que o meu e irei **apagar** esta pergunta. -- Meu me no momento só foi depreciar as respostas que já coloquei no site e não a minha pontuação.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Há mais de uma pessoa, e mais de uma ocorrência, como fatores aqui. Não acho que alguém tenha dito que você fez qualquer coisa de errado (exceto prometer parar de comentar sobre seus votos contra). Não há certos ou errados aqui, e ninguém está apontando o dedo. Por mim a pergunta pode ficar, mas é direito seu apagá-la.

Comment: @Gabe não quero dizer que irei apaga-la por ser ou não proveitosa, o motivo é evitar falsas acusações, o que eu acho que foi o meu principal erro. Do meu ponto de vista justificar ou não é um direito meu. Prometer claramente que nunca mais vou justificar, pode ter sido errado apenas por poder influenciar outros colaboradores a fazerem o mesmo, ou seja não que influenciar ninguém. -- No entanto irei aguardar alguns minutos antes de decidir deletar ou não, devido ao seu comentário. Acredite eu sou uma pessoa que tenta ver todos os lados e por isto estou tentando ver pela seu ponto de vista :)

Comment: Concordo com o @Gabe, não apagues a pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sem problemas. Definitivamente a decisão de comentar ou não pós downvote é totalmente pessoal (assim como de apagar a pergunta). Mas se você tem o hábito de fazer isso, lembre-se de que ele causa muito mais benefício ao site do que as raras vezes em que algo assim acontece :)

Comment: Pra tu ver, tomei outro -1 agora :( -- Como sofri uma perseguição semelhante no SOen fico com o pé atrás. Tenha paciência rs.