# Markdown @downvoter em comentários para notificar usuários que negativaram uma pergunta ou resposta

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, voto-contra, markdown

Um problema na comunidade é receber votos negativos sem explicação, então tive essa ideia, uma forma de falar com os usuários que negativaram a pergunta ou resposta, podendo perguntar o por que ou pedindo ajuda para melhorar, mantendo o anonimato do usuário (já que o mesmo não é obrigado a responder, ou pode responder omitindo o fato de ser o downvoter)

Comment: A ideia seria ativar uma notificação (por exemplo) quando o usuário comentar @downvoter?

Comment: Mas e se ele responder, aí acabou o anonimato, não? Ou a resposta também seria anônima?

Comment: @bio sim, igual ao `@bio`

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, mas aí é decisão do downvoter, ele não é obrigado. Assim como o usuário que negativa pode revelar sua identidade comentando o por que da resposta ser ruim depois de negativa-la

Comment: Mas um dos motivos de votar sem comentar (não que seja o principal, mas em muitos casos é, infelizmente) é justamente se manter anônimo para evitar [isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4162/112052). Não vejo como uma notificação faria a pessoa mudar de ideia e comentar. Já vi inclusive casos em que a pessoa pergunta o motivo do downvote, alguém explica (considerando casos em que a pergunta de fato tinha problemas) e a pessoa se revolta mesmo assim (muitas vezes com quem comentou, que não necessariamente é quem votou), então uma notificação não ajudaria muito nesses casos...

Comment: @hkotsubo retaliação é tratada pelo sistema automaticamente não? E qualquer coisa tem os moderadores para intervir e o meta pra pedir ajuda

Comment: Retaliação só é revertida quando são muitos votos (sendo que "muitos" é definido por algum algoritmo complicado que só a SE sabe, pois já vi casos em que nem todos são revertidos). Eu confesso que geralmente fico com receio de comentar justamente para não passar por essa chateação, mesmo sabendo que vai ser revertido. E receber uma notificação não me faria mudar de ideia. Aliás, as últimas vezes que resolvi comentar, foi péssimo, a pessoa se recusou a reconhecer o erro (e ela recebeu mais downvotes além do meu) e foi bem mal-educada. Enfim, concluí que na maioria das vezes não vale a pena...

Comment: @hkotsubo então é só ignorar, mas muitos podem ser ajudados e melhorarem a pergunta ou resposta

Comment: Acho válido. Um comentário [sempre é bem-vindo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/654/5043), embora não obrigatório, ajuda o AP a melhorar a pergunta e saber onde errou. Já vi entrarei em uma pergunta, negativar e simplesmente esquecer que ela existe, uma notificação poderia ajudar e ainda manteria a decisão de se manter no anonimato à aquele que negativou.

Comment: Isto foi proposto diversas vezes e sempre foi recusado, acho até que é duplicata. Se a pessoa não quis comentar não adianta forçar ela falar alguma coisa. É só criar um complicador e a pessoa vai parar de negativar, e todos perdem. Eu acho que deveria ter outras soluções para certos problemas.

Comment: Não seria bom pra comunidade isso. Muitos novato iriam ofende ou algo mais toxico,deve deixa voto -1 anonimato. Eu não importo se um usuário sabe que fiz um downvote,mas muito usuários se sentiriam desconfortável.

Comment: esse é um problema recorrente, às vezes desanima trabalhar uma resposta, gastar um tempo nela e ver um downvote injustificado... por outro lado se fizer vc perder o direito ao anonimato além de deixar as coisas mais engessadas, o usuário pode sofrer retalhações e desistir de dar um downvote. Talvez funcionaria se ao negativar tivesse de justificar e permanecer o comentário anônimo, seria um meio termo, daria pelo menos para notar se alguém justificou algo infundado, mas isso talvez demandasse muito trabalho para um sistema que já funciona bem, não acredito que isso vá adiante

Comment: Tem também um *corner case*: e se tiver um usuário chamado downvoter e ele já deixou um comentário? Nesse caso ele seria notificado, e não o downvoter de fato. Talvez seja improvável, mas não é impossível: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164011/downvoter